# Choose template method if type/class has field

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

Assume I have the following two types:

```
enum class TypeA {
    //...
};

class TypeB {
public:
    using _type = unsigned int;
    constexpr _type to_type();
    //...
};
```

I would like to design a SFINAE template method such that **Version 1** is chosen if the type T is a normal enum (i.e., does not have _type) and **Version 2** is chosen if it does have the typedef `_type`.

**Version 1** (if T is a normal enum):

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr std::underlying_type_t<T> underlying_cast(T p) { return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(p); }
```

**Version 2**:

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr typename T::_type underlying_cast(T p) { return p.to_type(); }
```

How would I go about this?  I would also really appreciate an explanation of how the SFINAE templates work in this case.

Comment: `inline` is pointless here. Not only do templates behave like `inline` functions anyway, `constexpr` also implies it.

Comment: Which C++ version are you targeting?

Comment: @user17732522 C++17, I added the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need a SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto underlying_cast(T p) { 
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(p);
    else return p.to_type();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o17ebbMxo